# Creating functions with if-statements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement

I'm fairly new to jQuery, and not very good at creating variables and functions, but I would like my code to be condensed and more "elegant".

Currently, my whole jQuery-code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    $('div.pane').scrollTo( 0 ),
    $.scrollTo( 0 ),
    $.localScroll({ duration:400,})
    );
```

( scrollTo/localScroll are two plugins. )

```
var gom = function (){$('#content').children().animate( {opacity: 0.4}, 200); }
var visa = function () {animate({opacity: 1 }, 400);}

$('#ntop').click(function (){
    gom();
});

$('#nmind').click(function (){
    gom();
    $('#secmind').animate({opacity: 1 }, 400);
});

$('#nheart').click(function (){
    gom();
    $('#secheart').animate({opacity: 1 }, 400);
});

$('#nhands').click(function (){
    gom();
    $('#sechands').animate({opacity: 1 }, 400);
});

$('#nfeet').click(function (){
    gom();
    $('#secfeet').animate({opacity: 1 }, 400);
});

$('#foot').click(function (){
    gom();
});

$('#secmind').mouseenter( function(){
    if($('#secmind').css('opacity') < '1') {
    gom();
    $('#secmind').animate({opacity: 1 }, 400); } 
});

$('#secheart').mouseenter( function(){
    if($('#secheart').css('opacity') < '1') {
    gom();
    $('#secheart').animate({opacity: 1 }, 400); } 
});

$('#sechands').mouseenter( function(){
    if($('#sechands').css('opacity') < '1') {
    gom();
    $('#sechands').animate({opacity: 1 }, 400); } 
});

$('#secfeet').mouseenter( function(){
    if($('#secfeet').css('opacity') < '1') {
    gom();
    $('#secfeet').animate({opacity: 1 }, 400); } 
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
         <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="b6.png" id="imgsimon" />
            <a name="sectop"></a>


        <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="ntop"> <a href="#sectop">Top</a> </li>
            <li id="nmind"> <a href="#secmind">Inspiration</a> </li>
            <li id="nheart"> <a href="#secheart">Interests</a> </li>
            <li id="nhands"> <a href="#sechands">Work</a> </li>
            <li id="nfeet"> <a href="#secfeet">Aspirations/Anticipations</a> </li>
            <li id="foot"> <a href="#secfooter">Contact Me!</a> </li>
        </ul>

    </div> 
    <div id="rubrik">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <p>Hey!</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <div class="text" id="secmind"><a name="secmind"></a>
            <h2>Inspiration</h2>
            <p>Bla bla</p>
        </div>  

        <div class="text" id="secheart"><a name="secheart"></a>
            <h2>Interests</h2>
            <p>Bla bla bla bla bla</p>
        </div>  


        <div class="text" id="sechands"><a name="sechands"></a>
            <h2>Work</h2>
            <p>Bla bla bla bla</p>
        </div>  

        <div class="text" id="secfeet"><a name="secfeet"></a>
            <h2>Aspirations / Anticipations</h2>
            <p>Bla bla bla</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer"><a name="secfooter"></a>
            <h2>Contact me!</h2>
            <p>Bla bla</p>
            <p>Bla bla</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "gom" function is working fine, but I don't know what the problem with "visa" is. Also, I'm assuming that you can write the if-functions in a more smooth way so you'd only have to write in once and not have to repeat it for every individual id.

Any help is welcome, the web page is working just fine, I just want to know how to write this in a better, faster and more elegant way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()`

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

in your `visa` function there is no selected element to be animated:

this:

```
 var visa = function () {animate({opacity: 1 }, 400);}
```

should be:

```
 var visa = function () { $('anElement').animate({opacity: 1 }, 400) }
```

also you can try selecting anchor elements instead of selecting each of them separately:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default action of the anchor link
    gom();
    var id = $(this).attr('href').remove('#',''); 
    $('#' + id).animate({opacity: 1 }, 400);
});

$('#content div').mouseenter( function(){
    if($(this).css('opacity') < '1') {
    gom();
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1 }, 400); } 
});
```